# unable to add a rdlc report to asp.net web applicatioin

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am adding the RDLC (report wizard) to my asp.net web application. I am using visual studio 2010 and have installed the AJAX control tool-kit using Nuget package manager.

Problem is arising at the point when I am adding a new item and then opting a new item as rdlc. then as I click over rdlc, instead of adding an rdlc to my project I am getting following error.

"could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral.... or one of its dependency."

I am unable to understand why i m getting this error. Kindly suggest some ways to add the rdlc smoothly.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Try copying the AJAXCONTROLTOOLKIT.DLL file to the following folder.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
Hope this works.**

It worked for me.

May be you get this problem again while adding Report Data also, if you are referencing to another business/ data layer project in the solution. Then also copy the dll of those projects to same folder as mentioned above.

Comment: I have made it working, however I have saved your suggestion on my machine. Thanks so much for a nice tip. :)